# Hex values in SQL Database - converting to decimal

Tags: sql, hex

I am working with a SQL database that contains a column of numbers in hex. The numbers are entered into a third party application as a decimal and are saved in the SQL database as a hex value. Only issue is I can't figure out how the hex values correspond to the decimal values.

Example:

> - 0x000000000032000000 is 50
> - 0x0000000000E9030000 is 1001
> - 0x00000000002C010000 is 300

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: 50 = 0x003c, 1001 = 0x03e9, and 300 = 0x012c, so these hex numbers are just slightly scrambled versions of the correct binary representations of your data.  What is the data type of the column in which these data are appearing?  And what DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CONVERT

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, 0xFFFFFF)
```